# Rigging weird shape problem, how to rig object that can rotate 90 degree naturally

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

[image: Example of weird shape being rigged]

[image: Example + image of natural shape]

May I know how to do rigging that can naturally rotate 90 degree?

Because left picture is my rigging shown that weird shape while rotate

Comment: i believe that is bendy bones in the small picture. select all those bones and in the **bone property tab** in **bendy bone section** hold Alt and increase segments max is 32 , you can then play with like ease in and out to get a nice result. (holding alt applys the change for all of selected bones)

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to correct the shape.  You can try using *corrective shape keys*, or you can edit your geometry and weight paint to make the topology more likely to bend in the desired way.

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235906/how-do-i-fix-this-bad-bending-in-my-minecraft-arm/237158#237158) for a detailed explanation of using weight painting and geometry to change the flexing.

[Corrective Shape Keys](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/animation/corrective_shape_keys.html) is a add-on that is included in Blender but that you need to activate before you use.  There are several good tutorials on their use on YouTube, but the basic idea is

- Create your geometry
- Pose your model
- Edit a copy of the geometry to achieve the shape you want
- Make this copy a shape key for the original geometry
- Use a driver to apply the shape key as part of the rotation of the object.