# Polys are stretched when posing. Weight painting doesn't seem to fix it fully

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

So this skeleton isn't a universal one, it's from Grand Theft Auto V and it's very strict on the amount of bones and bone type, so changing the rig is out of the question. I tried using subdivide on the part of the leg and it seemed to look a bit better, but it would not smooth out afterwards.

I'm running Blender 2.8.

Comment: Here is my .blend

https://blend-exchange.com/b/4emLsaWr

Comment: It's not the rig, it's the geometry of the mesh.  It's stretching because there's not enough geometry for it to not stretch.  See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235906/how-do-i-fix-this-bad-bending-in-my-minecraft-arm/237158#237158) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is duplicated vertices and bad *Custom Split Normals*.

First, select the mesh (*lowr_000_r_high*), go to *Edit* mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* to get rid of 8871 duplicated vertices.

Furthermore, it looks like the mesh is optimized for a game engine. It has tris, *Auto Smooth* is enabled, and there is *Custom Split Normals Data*. The *Custom Split Normals Data* seems to be messed up at the knee area.

You can fix the shading this way: (The order is important!)

1. switch to *Object* mode, right-click the mesh object, select *Shade Smooth*. It will look worse. No worries.
2. add a *Weighted Normal* modifier. It goes after the *Armature* modifier (see screenshot)
3. apply the added modifier. This will recreate/override the *Custom Split Normals Data*. The shading will change a little bit and there is a warning. This is because the modifier is not the first on the stack. But the result will be fine.

[image: screenshot of the model]

---

Note: If you don't like the shading you need to delete the *Custom Split Normals Data* and disable *Object Data Properties > Normals > Auto Smooth*.

[image: clear the custom split normals data]