# Blender auto-morphs like Daz3D?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have one small question that I'am unable to formulate correctly to find an answer.

In Daz3D there is some morph-system or something that automatically adjusts unrealistic bending of mesh in required spots while moving/rotating bones in viewport.
Pictured explanations attached:
[image: Daz3D example][image: Blender example]

Question is: are there any similar scripts/addons/something that can replicate such behavour in Blender?

Comment: "Preserve Volume"? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237245/2214

Comment: You can additionally try to add a _Smooth Corrective_ modifier after the _Armature_ modifier, this might help a little as well.